# How do I change the temporary directory without using any administrative pages provided by Drupal?

Tags: files

I've moved my live Drupal website to Windows localhost (XAMPP), but I'm getting lots of "The file could not be created" errors. If I log in to the site as an administrator, it fails to return any more pages at all. I can view it with errors if I don't log in.

Is there a way to change the temporary file location without logging in through the interface, or using any administrative page?

Comment: From the problem description, it doesn't really sound like the temporary file path is the problem, but I answered that question below, since that's the title. Please re-phrase the question text so that it goes more in line with the title.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Drupal 7 the temporary path is stored in the variable `file_temporary_path`, so you can either update the entry in the `variables` table with a SQL-query. Or you can use [Drush](http://www.drush.org/):

`drush vset file_temporary_path [some_new_path]`.

Answer (score 8):

For Drupal 8 using [Drush](http://www.drush.org/):

```
drush config-set system.file path.temporary /tmp
```

Answer (score 7):

Variables can be overwritten within `settings.php`. An entry like the following will do it in D7:

```
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = '/tmp';
```

Replace `'/tmp'` with your specific path. You might also need to set the variable `file_private_path`.